# Convert sql row into columns

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table:

```
A    B     c
a1   1     a11
a1   2     a12
a1   3     a13
a2   1     a21
a2   2     a22
a2   3     a23
```

and I want to convert it to:

```
A     C1     C2     C3
a1    a11    a12    a13
a2    a21    a22    a23
```

How can I write a SQL query to achieve this... I do not want to convert my table to csv and use python and do it...

Comment: Take a look at ['How to pivot rows into columns'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120835/how-to-pivot-rows-into-columns-custom-pivoting).

Comment: Just to clarify some. Do you want to break out the C column into multiple columns based on the values in the B column? Are you trying to replace the first table design or are you trying to write a query which will keep the first table design in place but pull the values for the second table design?

Comment: I want to have a view of the table with this design.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT A,
MAX(CASE WHEN B=1 THEN c END) AS C1,
MAX(CASE WHEN B=2 THEN c END) AS C2, // etc for B=3,4
FROM table1
GROUP BY A
```