# How to generate CSV for the following qry in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select ct.TEST_OPTION_NAME ,
cx.cert_id FROM CERT_TEST_OPTION Ct join 
cert_x_test_option Cx
on ct.test_option_ID = cx.test_option_id;
```

Current OUtput:

> Third Party Exam Center    0014
>
> Online Exam    0014
>
> On Site    0014
>
> National Conference    0014

Looking for output as:

> Third Party Exam Center,Online Exam,On Site,National Conference    0014

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to export query result to csv in Oracle SQL Developer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168398/how-to-export-query-result-to-csv-in-oracle-sql-developer)

Comment: Please post some sample data and desired result

Comment: This is the output iam currently gettign for that qry i mentioned in the qs: 0014 Online Exam
0014 National Conference
0014 On Site
0014 Third Party Exam Center

Comment: Iam looking for 0014 Online Exam,National Conference,On Site

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. You are selecting two fields, test_option_name and cert_id. You show that long string - which part is the first field returned by the query, and which is the second? Also, in your current output you show four options but in the desired output you only show three; what happened to Third Party Exam Center? Please put a little more effort in stating your problem and your requirement. Show: table ct has the following columns (...) and some of the values are (...)  - and make sure you show ROWS of values if the table has more than one column.

Comment: Comments editor formated my text to single line. But my qry result is actually giving 4 rows with name and iD  on each row.and Iam looking for a sinlge row with comma separated values.Check below in the answer section

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to pivot rows into columns.  Take a look at this:
[How to pivot rows into columns (custom pivoting)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120835/how-to-pivot-rows-into-columns-custom-pivoting)

Once you have your desired results in columns, you should be able to export as CSV using

```
select /*csv*/ .....
```

Comment: In what does this answer the question?